# jquery jqm .closest span

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a jquery mobile listview and a user will click on one of the li which will activate my delete code.  All that is working. The problem is that I need to reduce the li count by one for each deleted li.

The listview looks like this (there are nine listviews on the page):

```
<div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true" data-inset="true">
  <h3>Robbery
  <span id="rob_count" class="ui-li-count" style="float:right;">3</span></h3>
  <ul id="robberyAlertList" data-role="listview">
  <li id="1" class="robbery">Some text</li>
  <li id="2" class="robbery">Some more text</li>
  <li id="3" class="robbery">Still more text</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Once the li is clicked my delete function is called and inside it (after the prompt to delete) I do this:

```
var nCnt = $("#" +msg_id).closest( "span" ).text();
           $("#" +msg_id).closest( "span" ).text(--nCnt);
           $('#' +msg_id).remove();
           $('#fetch-result').html("Alert was deleted!");
```

What I'm trying to do is is get the text inside the span (3) and reduce it by 1. What's happening is the li is being deleted, the #fetch-result is being set but nothing else. I don't think I'mt getting the span above the li and I'm certainly not getting the 3.

My guess is that I'm not doing something right with the .closest.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Just FYI, element IDs are not supposed to start with numbers.

Comment: @Cᴏʀʏ That's not true since HTML5.

Comment: @Gothdo: Right you are. HTML5 ids pretty much just can't contain spaces or be empty. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting with the element itself, `closest()` looks up the DOM tree, parent by parent, so it will not find the `span` you're looking for since it's a child of a *sibling* of a parent (think cousin). Also, instead of trying to get the current count and reducing it, I would simply count the remaining list items and put a new count in its place:

```js
function removeMessage(msg_id) {
    var $toRemove = $('#' + msg_id); // element to remove
    var $list = $toRemove.parent('ul'); // element's parent
    $toRemove.remove(); // remove it
    var newCount = $list.find('li').length;
    $list.closest('div').find('.ui-li-count').text(newCount); // get and show new count
}

removeMessage('1');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true" data-inset="true">
  <h3>Robbery
  <span id="rob_count" class="ui-li-count" style="float:right;">3</span></h3>
  <ul id="robberyAlertList" data-role="listview">
  <li id="1" class="robbery">Some text</li>
  <li id="2" class="robbery">Some more text</li>
  <li id="3" class="robbery">Still more text</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: But the span is above the li... and the ul... which is why I'm confused about it.

Comment: @ppetree: It goes up the tree parent by parent. The `<span>` is never a *parent* of the `<li>`, it's just a sibling of one of its parents (the `<ul>`).

Comment: @Cory - I was just trying your snippet... stepping through it in the debugger.  It pulled all the right info, all the vars had the right values but when it came to setting the newCount (which was set to 19) in the span, nothing changed.

Comment: Is the HTML in the example exactly a match to your code? The snippet above works, so check your markup. Also, jQuery needs your element ids to be unique. You can't have multiple `<li>` with the same id (which maybe looks like the case, if you have multiple collapsible sections with an unordered list and each list item starts at id 1.

Comment: Yes. Other than the id's are in the 80's. Each of the id's are unique record numbers (messages from the server) but, on the page, there are 9 total listviews each with spans having the class of ui-li-count. Each listview has a different type of message (robbery, shooting etc) and each can contain n messages. When a user clicks on an li it loads the message contents, draws a map etc.  on a click-hold (long press) it pops up the delete prompt.  I separated out your last line and assigned it to a var nCnt = $list.closest('div').find('.ui-li-count').text(); and that didn't give me the existing 21.

Comment: Here are the variables from stepping through... $toRemove = li#82.robberyAlertList; $list = ul#robberyAlertList.ui-listview; newCount = 18.  I'll have to take this up tomorrow...

Comment: @ppetree, Query Mobile adds extra markup to create the collapsible, so to find and change the count, do this:  $list.closest('.ui-collapsible').find('.ui-li-count').text(newCount); (basically you have to to grandparent div instead of parent)

Comment: Yeah, I figured it out this morning... Cory got me close and after an hour of mucking around I managed to get it to work.  @ezanker your solution is even better than what I came up with. Thanks!  And thank you Cory.